# How do I turn off edge scrolling?

Tags: touchpad

How do I turn off edge scrolling? I went to the touchpad settings and none of the choices would turn it off.

Comment: can you mention which device(Laptop) are you using. I had similar problem in my Dell Vostro and I installed synaptic pointing device(software) and I was able to configure it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, from a command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad scroll-method "disabled"
```

If your hardware support it, you can try

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad scroll-method 'two-finger-scrolling'
```

which I find much less invasive. With my touchpad, the options are:

```
% gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad scroll-method
enum
'disabled'
'edge-scrolling'
'two-finger-scrolling'
```

I am not sure about which flavor of Ubuntu/DE you have, so I explain how I found it: I launched `dconf-editor` (if you do not have it, install the package with the same name), and using Find -> "edge" I had (after clicking three or four times "next") this screen:

[image: dconf-editor discovering option]

For using the command line `gsettings` you have to look at the Schema: path in the description of the key.

Comment: I did as you say, but edge scrolling is still active on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `dconf-editor` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If Rmano's answer doesn't work for you, it may be because you have a Synaptics touchpad, which will have its own settings in addition to the Gnome ones. You can check by running

```
xinput list
```

at the command line and looking for the touchpad entry.

If you do have a Synaptics touchpad, run

```
synclient
```

to list its settings.  You can then change them by running commands like

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
```